# accessing pictures in my exe of wpf app from codebehind

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

im currently accessing my image in XAML and setting it to a picturebox with

```
Source="/SocialShock-WPF-Client;component/Images/blue-bar-replication.png"
```

how would i do this in the codebehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static BitmapImage GetImageFromResource(string name)
    {
        var res = new BitmapImage();
        res.BeginInit();
        res.StreamSource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("SocialShock-WPF-Client.Images." + name);
        res.EndInit();

        return res;
    }
```

Invoke this method with the image name, "blue-bar-replication.png" in your case.
The image build action should be set to EmbededResource.

Comment: `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
System.InvalidOperationException: Property 'UriSource' or property 'StreamSource' must be set.
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
   at .BottomBarUserControl.GetImageFromResource(String name) in ...BottomBarUserControl.xaml.cs:line 71
   at SocialShock_WPF_Client.BottomBarUserControl..ctor() in ...BottomBarUserControl.xaml.cs:line 55
System.InvalidOperationException: Property 'UriSource' or property 'StreamSource' must be set.`

Comment: are you sure the name, namespace and directory is correct? try Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() and check if your image appears in the list

Comment: ah, with a little bit closer analysis, i found a typo. after fixing it, it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way. Create [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) object (pass [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object with the same path to its [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473.aspx)). Then set Image's Source property to the newly created BitmapImage object.

Comment: @Tommy yes, I added the reference to corresponding constructor.